# Laravel on server not loading home.blade.php

Tags: laravel, voyager

On the server the home page is not loading with home.blade.php, it's loading with some default template but it's not welcome.blade.php. On the local server, it's working fine but on the server, it's not loading.

I am using VOYAGER package for admin. when I am trying to load /page/home its working fine but with / its not working.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $posts = App\Post::all();
    $pages = App\Page::all();
    $homepage = App\Page::where('slug', '=', 'home')->firstOrFail();
    return view('home', compact('posts','pages','homepage'));
});
```

Comment: its not working with https://unionflooringcompany.theportlandcompany.com/ but its working with https://unionflooringcompany.theportlandcompany.com/page/home

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post some code. This way we can help you much quicker and understand the problem better

Comment: abdul, you can edit your question and the code there so that its more readable

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: No. there is no error. its loading content from VOYAGER admin. But without my header and footer. Its not loading my home template when i am trying to load https://unionflooringcompany.theportlandcompany.com/